# VBA to query on mysql

Tags: mysql, vba, odbc

I am really new in mysql. I managed to query some data on our mysql data base through macro recording but somehow, I would like to edit the **commandtext** to add some "JOIN, WHERE etc". Below is the recorded macro which is working fine. Thanks!

Sub Macro1()

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=MySQL Excel;Extended Properties=""DSN=MySQL Excel;"";Initial Catalog=Mfg" _
    , ""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array("`Mfg`.`kgbRun`")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "C:\Users\atanacic\Documents\My Data Sources\Mfg.odc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Mfg15"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: No knowledge/access to *mysql*, but think you should edit this line `.CommandText = Array("'Mfg'.'kgbRun'")`

Comment: Thanks patrick but Array type  won't work.

Comment: What I meant is that the command is passed in `.CommandText`. Perhaps you need to use *ADODB.Connection* instead. Some sources like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2vnm99/using_vba_to_pull_data_from_mysql_to_excel_with/)